# Error al leer JSON con PHP

Tags: php, json, api

Tengo una URL que me entrega un valor de moneda USD al día de hoy, sin embargo estoy teniendo problemas para poder leer el dato y trabajarlo en mi sitio

La URL entrega como JSON lo siguiente:

```
{
  "Dolares": 
  [
    {
      "Valor": "810,64",
      "Fecha": "2023-04-05"
    }
  ]
}
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$apiUrl_USD = 'https://api.cmfchile.cl/api-sbifv3/recursos_api/dolar?apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&formato=json'; // aca va la url de la api que entrega el resultado anterior
$USD_json = file_get_contents($apiUrl_USD); 
$decoded_json = json_decode($USD_json, true);
$valor_usd = $decoded_json["Dolares"][0]["Valor"];

echo "<p>USD: ".$valor_usd."</p>";
```

Sin embargo el resultado que muestra es:

> USD:

Hasta hace poco me funcionaba pero no se que pasó que no puedo leer el dato.

Comment: IMPORTANTE: Si ese api Key es pago no debes colocarlo en la pregunta formulada por cuestiones de seguridad.

Comment: Okey el código se ve bien, lo que debes hacer es comprobar si esa URL trae datos y por otro lado que siempre traiga monto a cualquier día de consulta. Vuelve a verificar las claves valor si son las mismas.

Comment: Hola Alberto, la api no es de pago, la puse para que justamente pudieran ver lo que muestra, pero tomaré el comentario y la sacaré. Lo que no entiendo es porque no me arroja resultado el codigo al ejecutarlo. La URL trae hoy justamente los datos mostrados en la pregunta. Y todos los días entrega esos datos.

Comment: Copié tu código tal cual y funciona https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaZHZ.png

Comment: Que raro, a mi no hay caso https://paste.pics/f36dc21a6cc1c5f9b5a7489274b34446

Comment: lo probé en un compilador y me muestra lo mismo que a mi: https://paste.pics/b4dbe48da273e6e6ebf57abbf70ef33a

Comment: Ya encontré el problema, probé la url en postman y me sale [enlace](https://paste.pics/d98548ab062d730d88d997f8baef0824) al parecer el certificado tiene problemas, si colocas http:// en lugar de https:// con eso ya funciona, espero ser de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

El código efectivamente está correcto. Pero hay un tema con el servidor de la URL al parecer con el SSL. Probé cambiando la url de la api de https a http y funcionó sin problemas

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta. Debes participar más para obtener reputación y poder comentar. Puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [answer] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu respuesta sea marcada como aceptada.